# Django ajax warning on same page after DoesNotExist exception on form POST

Tags: ajax, django, post

I have a django form attached to a view. In the form a user types in a query which is passed to a Model.objects.get( query ) like so:

```
   def post(self, request):
     try:
       Model.objects.get(query)
     except Model.DoesNotExist:
       # something here
```

Upon exception i'd like to send an ajax request to my template that stops it from refreshing, and displays a warning to the user that there's nothing in the database matching that get request. What would I put in the view and the template?

Answer (score 0):

The http standard response would be a 404 response. Django has a shortcut function for this: [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

```
def post(self, request):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(Model, query)
```

If the lookup fails, django will raise an 404 error, which will result in a 404 http response back to the client. In your javascript ajax handling code, you should check the http status, and handle any 404 responses appropriately.

For example, if you are using the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the code might look like this.

```
fetch('/some/url/?query=foobar').then(response => { 
  if (response.ok) return response.json()
  if (response.status == 404) throw new Error('404')
})
```